# view not updating when removing items from formArray

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a formArray set up like,

in the constructor:

```
this.createUserFormList = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([])
    });
```

in ngOnInit:

```
(<FormArray>this.createUserFormList.controls['items'])
  .push(this.fb.group({
    createName: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3)
    ]),
    createEmail: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email
    ]),
    createOrganisation: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required
    ]),
    createRole: new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required
    ])
  }))
```

Users can add more groups to the array, which works fine, but now I need them to be able to be deleted.

I've tried below way, but doesn't work:

```
removeUserForm(index) {
  this.createUserFormList.controls['items'].value.splice(index, 1);
  //this seem to remove from array when logging however the view does not update
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove items from **formarray itself** via `removeAt(index)`.

```
removeUserForm(index) {
  (<FormArray>this.createUserFormList.controls['items']).removeAt(index);
}
```

see **[details](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#adding-or-removing-controls)** and **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slrufk?file=app/app.component.ts)**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer pengyy, however I get the error, splice does not exist on type form array

Comment: @Roy sorry, you should use `removeAt`, it's different from normal Array. See added demo.

Comment: its not working for me